# Не отображаются рисунки в JSP (Spring MVC resource mapping)

Tags: spring, mvc, java

У меня упорно не хотят отображаться рисунки в jsp, хотя в конфигурационном файле прописано

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/">
```

Сервлет прописан вот так

```
<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Но все ссылки на `/resources/image.jpg` не отображают результат

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась прописыванием абсолютного пути к рисункам. Что-то вроде `http://localhost:8080/abc/resources/trava.jpg`. Наверное, я где-то затупила... Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если рисунок отобразился, значит, вы неверно написали путь в первый раз. Как вариант можно попробовать `/abc/resources/trava.jpg`, т.к. путь абсолютный, а корень `localhost`